# How to compare proportion of a category in a sample vs its proportion in a population

Tags: mathematical-statistics, categorical-data, proportion, sample, population

No. of observations in the dataset = 19,277
There are 2 features : Country & Job role.
There are 5641 respondents from a country, India.
There are 5171 respondents that are students.
Of the 5641 respondents from India, 2242 are students.

I want to compare how much the proportion of students changes in India as compared with the overall proportion.
Here are 2 simple approaches,
$$1 \Rightarrow \frac{2242}{5641} - \frac{5171}{19277} = -\ 0.1292$$
$$2 \Rightarrow \frac{2242}{5171} - \frac{5641}{19277} = -\ 0.1409$$

**Queries:**

1. Which one of the above 2 is more sensible or statistically appropriate?
2. Is there any other better approach?
3. Would it be correct to say that "the representation of India in the student population increases by around 12.92 percentage points compared with its overall representation in the population" ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont have enought information to answer 3rd question. You want to use "increase", but it requires time series or more data to check on how proportion was changing.

In your case you may only say that "on the average" there is 12.92% more students in India than in the whole dataset (world etc). From that, perspective option 1) is more reasonable because you compare number of students to the sample.